# removing something from a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to be able to find a tag, and only remove part of what is in the tag. like

```
<p>some text. remove this with jQuery</p>
```

with the out put being something like

```
<p>some text</p>
```

with out completely removing the tag and setting it as something else or just like resetting the html of the html tag?

Comment: You can get the `text()` or `html()`, manipulate the string however you want, and then use the same methods to set the value back.

Comment: What have you tried? Also there is alot of examples on SO on how to do this.

Comment: Um...no? As far as HTML is concerned, everything inside that <p> tag is a single string, a single text node, a single element. If you want to modify part of it, the only way is to get the current value, change it, and then replace the entire contents with the changed version. So you'll always have to "reset the HTML of the HTML tag" -- why are you against doing that?

Comment: If I am constantly changing the value of the body but can't read it, how do I change something with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to determine how you want to select the element you wish to edit. You can select elements by id, by class, by the element itself, or by its position in the DOM.

A simple example would be:

```js
function handleButton() {
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = "We have replaced the text in this element.";
}
```

```html
<p id="example">Replace the text in this element.</p>
<button onClick="handleButton()">Replace Text</button>
```